# shared memory with seamphore

Tags: c, fork, semaphore, shared-memory

i am having difficulties implementing shared memory with this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int mutex=1,full=0,empty=3,x=0;

int main()
{
    int n;
    void producer();
    void consumer();
    int wait(int);
    int signal(int);
    printf("\n1.Producer\n2.Consumer\n3.Exit");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\nEnter your choice:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        switch(n)
        {
            case 1:    if((mutex==1)&&(empty!=0))
                        producer();
                    else
                        printf("Buffer is full!!");
                    break;
            case 2:    if((mutex==1)&&(full!=0))
                        consumer();
                    else
                        printf("Buffer is empty!!");
                    break;
            case 3:
                    exit(0);
                    break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int wait(int s)
{
    return (--s);
}

int signal(int s)
{
    return(++s);
}

void producer()
{
    mutex=wait(mutex);
    full=signal(full);
    empty=wait(empty);
    x++;
    printf("\nProducer produces the item %d",x);
    mutex=signal(mutex);
}

void consumer()
{
    mutex=wait(mutex);
    full=wait(full);
    empty=signal(empty);
    printf("\nConsumer consumes item %d",x);
    x--;
    mutex=signal(mutex);
}
```

at the moment `x` is just a normal variable but if i want to fork it using a parent.c file how can i use a shared memory here so that both producer and consumer runs together
i am unable to use shared memory with this code also notable to find a good documentation online

Comment: Consider using shmget.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What kind of sadist would advise using SysV IPC? Consider using `shm_open()`.

Comment: @EOF: please substantiate your value judgement for the OP.